# Im not receiving any angular testing output

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

It is my first time using angular test and im a bit stuck.

the problem is that the output of the "ng test" generated html is empty when i've put some code in the spec file of the component

This is the spec file of the component im trying to test. (I was trying to test the angular test just to see if it works)

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
// import { instance, mock, verify, when } from "ts-mockito";
import { TopnavComponent } from "./topnav.component";
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe("TopnavComponent", () => {
  let component: TopnavComponent;
  let token = ""

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TopnavComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should retrieve kindai image', async(()=>{
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("test")).value = '1';
  
    expect((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("test")).value).toBe('2')
  }))
});
```

when i execute ng test the output is this:

[image]

and the debug site is a blank html (no console errors)

this is the karma.conf:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
      basePath: '../..',
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      //...
    });
  };
```

what im missing? it is not supposed to show an output with the spec file code?

Comment: Probably you are missing reporters.

Comment: Or your tests are not ran.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing reporters. This is set a of reporters that I am using

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('karma-junit-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
```

keep in mind that you have to install plugins you want to use using `npm` first. In your case, `karma-jasmine-html-reporter` should be enough